# Automatically arrange several images to fit a whole web page

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, computational-geometry

Given a bunch a images of different size and ratio, but all rectangular, is there a easy way in javascript/css to assemble them so they fit the whole web page. Such as :

[image]

Given the following constraints :

- Images could be, in the process, can be resized down independently, but not up.
- The resizing down should have a size limit (so image could still be visible).
- Images can be reordered at will to fit the best packing
- Ratio must be preserved.

Is there generic/formal terms to describe this process so I can better search for solutions ?

I guess there is no easy, ready-to-use way to do this, like a js library. But does it exist an algorithm that would handle this operation, like form a geometrical point of view of assembling rectangle to fit a bigger rectangle ?

Comment: What you're looking for is something called `mosaic`. Have a look at this http://masonry.desandro.com/. Maybe will help you.

Comment: Two critical questions here: (1) Are ALL IMAGES resized at the same time or each image can be resized independently of the others? (2) Is the order of the image fixed or they can be reordered to achieve the best **packing**?

Comment: 1) each image can be resized independently of the others 2) they can be reordered to achieve the best packing

Answer (score 3):

Have you thought about alighning the images in columns and then using CSS media queries to reorganize them acordingly to the size of the web page... 
Something like this: https://css-tricks.com/seamless-responsive-photo-grid/

Comment: @Quentin I would post it as a coment but because of not having enough "reputation" i can't post soments... so hope that anwsers your question :)